# Error when creating a copy of ViewModel object

Tags: knockout-2.0

I'm trying to create a copy of my ViewModel object by serializing and deserializing it:

```
       var copyOfObj=  ko.mapping.fromJSON(ko.toJSON(myViewModel))
```

If i do some manipulation on objects i got following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Accessing selectionDirection on an input element that cannot have a selection.

Hope someone will be able to explain me this issue

Thanks

P.S.
Now i'm starting to think it is something to do with edit dialog form with inputs binded to values of this view model

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was seeing this same issue, and in my case it was due to a jQuery object as a property of my viewmodel. It was infinite looping for a reason I'm not sure of.

Once I removed the property, everything started working